# Enable reply / forward on iMessage Extension custom messages

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Let's say we have the following code in our iMessage extension that inserts our custom images:

```
class MessageUtil {
    static func insertImageIntoConversation(_ image: UIImage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Create an MSMessage with the UIImage
        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.image = image
        let message = MSMessage()
        message.layout = layout
        
        
        
        // Insert the message into the conversation
        conversation.insert(message, completionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to insert message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Message inserted successfully")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

We are facing the issue that recipients cannot reply / forward as they would with a normal message as those functions are disabled when tapping on the message on the receiving end.

The question therefore is: how would it be possible to enable reply and forward with custom messages?